# Drawing a chart on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, drawing

Is it possible to have a chart with

left x axis

top Y axis

all on same chart?

I tried switch the value of X and Y but it does not change the location of and y axises.

Comment: When you select the data, you can click "switch data"

Comment: I might have an answer for you - but could you clarify the question?  It looks to me like you want a scatter plot with a horizontal axis on the top only, and a vertical axis on the left only.  The question of which axis is "X" and which is "Y" doesn't actually mean much to excel - you just select which data you want on the horizontal and which you want on the vertical.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use scatter chart if you want to see better result of X and Y value.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: is there any app can let me draw it?